# Only half of the BinaryDocument(s) are getting inserted during bulk insert

Tags: java, json, serialization, couchbase, rx-java

I am having a weird problem during insertion. I have two types of documents - JSON and BinaryDocument. I am performing bulk insert operation restricted to a batch size.

The operation works fine for JSON documents. But if I upload, say 100 documents, then only 50 are getting upload in the case of BinaryDocument. Every time only half the number of documents are getting loaded in the database.

Here is my code for JSON document insertion:

```
public void createMultipleCustomerDocuments(String docId, Customer myCust, long numDocs, int batchSize) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonObject content = JsonObject.fromJson(gson.toJson(myCust));
        JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.create(docId, content);
        jsonDocuments.add(document);
        documentCounter.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("Batch size: " + batchSize + " Document Counter: " + documentCounter.get());
        if(documentCounter.get() >= batchSize){
            System.out.println("Document counter: " + documentCounter.get());
            Observable
            .from(jsonDocuments)
            .flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                public Observable<JsonDocument> call(final JsonDocument docToInsert) {
                    return theBucket.async().upsert(docToInsert);
                }
            })
            .last()
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
            jsonDocuments.clear();
            documentCounter.set(0);
        }


    }
```

This works completely fine. I have no problem in insertion.

Here is the code for my BinaryDocument insertion:

```
public void createMultipleCustomerDocuments(final String docId, ByteBuffer myCust, long numDocs, int batchSize) throws BackpressureException, InterruptedException {
        ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(myCust);
        binaryDocuments.add(buffer);
        documentCounter.incrementAndGet();

        System.out.println("Batch size: " + batchSize + " Document Counter: " + documentCounter.get());

        if(documentCounter.get() >= batchSize){
            System.out.println("Document counter: " + documentCounter.get() + " Binary Document list size: " + binaryDocuments.size());
            Observable
            .from(binaryDocuments)
            .flatMap(new Func1<ByteBuf, Observable<BinaryDocument>>() {
                public Observable<BinaryDocument> call(final ByteBuf docToInsert) {
                    //docToInsert.retain();

                    return theBucket.async().upsert(BinaryDocument.create(docId, docToInsert));

                } 
            })
            .last()
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();

            binaryDocuments.clear();

            documentCounter.set(0);
        }
     }
```

This fails. Exactly half the number of documents get inserted. Even the numbers are printed in exactly the same manner as of JSON document's function's numbers. The documentCounter shows the correct number. But the number of documents that get inserted in the DB is only the half of what it is shown.

Can someone please help me this?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `if(documentCounter.get() >= batchSize){` when there is no `else` clause?

Comment: @EJP I need to push in the documents into the DB only if the list's size equals the batch's size. If not, I just need to continue inserting the documents inside the list.

Comment: Regarding your code, only the last document of your batch will be inserted (because of the `last` operator). Is it expected ?

Comment: @dwursteisen That is given in the Couchbase's documentation for bulk insert. `last()` is to wait insert them in one batch, waiting until the last one is done.

Reference: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.0/documents-bulk.html

Scroll down to see **Batching Mutations**. You can find the documented code.

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using?

Comment: @RoiKatz Version 2.2.0 Community edition. Build - 837.

Comment: First, I can strongly suggest you to try it with a newer version of Couchbase.

Comment: @RoiKatz I have installed the latest version. I am still not able to understand why it isn't showing the version number as 4.5!

Comment: I don't know why, I did upgrade in my home and it worked well.
you do need to uninstall the previous version first.

Comment: @RoiKatz Did you check the server's version in WebUI's About ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the same document id (i.e the docId of the last member of the batch) to create all documents in the same batch

```
.BinaryDocument.create(docId, docToInsert)
```

You should build up your array of BinaryDocument outside the if statement (like you did with the JsonDocument version). Something like

```
public void createMultipleCustomerDocuments(final String docId, ByteBuffer myCust, int batchSize) throws BackpressureException, InterruptedException {
    //  numDocs is redundant
    ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(myCust);
    binaryDocuments.add(BinaryDocument.create(docId, buffer)); // ArrayList<BinaryDocument> type
    documentCounter.incrementAndGet();

    System.out.println("Batch size: " + batchSize + " Document Counter: " + documentCounter.get());

    if(documentCounter.get() >= batchSize){
        System.out.println("Document counter: " + documentCounter.get() + " Binary Document list size: " + binaryDocuments.size());
        Observable
        .from(binaryDocuments)
        .flatMap(new Func1<BinaryDocument, Observable<BinaryDocument>>() {
            public Observable<BinaryDocument> call(final BinaryDocument docToInsert) {
                return theBucket.async().upsert(docToInsert);
            } 
        })
        .last()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
        binaryDocuments.clear();
        documentCounter.set(0);
    }
}
```

should work.